# Mysql Group By and Sum performance issues

Tags: mysql

We have just one table with millions of rows where this query, as it stands takes 138 seconds to run on a server with a buffer pool size of 25G, the server itself linux with SSD drives.

I am wondering if anyone could suggest any improvements in MySQL settings or in the query itself that would reduce run time.  We only have about 8 large member_id's that have this performance problem, the rest run under 5 seconds. We run multiple summary tables like this for rollup reporting.

```
select * 
from (
 SELECT distinct account_name AS source,SUM(royalty_amount) AS total_amount
 FROM royalty_stream
 WHERE member_id = '1050705'
    AND deleted = 0  
    AND period_year_quarter >= '2016_Q1'
    AND period_year_quarter <= '2016_Q2'    
 GROUP BY account_name
 ORDER BY total_amount desc 
 LIMIT 1
 ) a
```

Comment: What's the schema of the table involved?

Comment: What is the explain output?

Comment: What's the purpose of `DISTINCT` in a `GROUP BY` query?

Comment: Looks like there is no need for the Distinct after your comments and others although that didn't change performance

Comment: Once we downselect on the member_id, we are running multiple rollups of sums and group by for different types of data.  One suggestion I see if using  a temporary table to put this data in for faster analysis.

Answer (score 2):

I see a few obvious improvements.

**Subselects**

Don't use a subselect. This isn't a huge deal, but it makes little sense to add the overhead here.

**Using Distinct**

Is the `distinct` really needed here? Since you're grouping, it should be unnecessary overhead.

**Data Storage Practices**

Your `period_year_quarter` evaluation is going to be a hurdle. String comparisons are one of the slower things you can do, unfortunately. If you have the ability to update the data structure, I would highly recommend that you break `period_year_quarter` into two distinct, integer fields. One for the year, one for the quarter.

Is royalty_amount actually stored as a number, or are you making the database implicitly convert it every time? If so (surprisingly common mistake) converting that to a number will also help.

**Indexing**

You haven't explained what indexes are on this table. I'm hoping that you at least have one on `member_id`. If not, it should certainly be indexed.

I would further recommend an index on `(member_id, period_year_quarter)`. If you took my advice from the previous section, that should be `(member_id, year, quarter)`.

---

```
select 
  account_name as source
  , sum(royalty_amount) as total_amount
from 
  royalty_stream
where 
  member_id                = '1050705'
  and deleted              = 0
  and period_year_quarter between '2016_Q1' and '2016_Q2'
group by 
  account_name
order by 
  total_amount desc 
limit 1
```

Comment: I'd also try with account_name in the index.  Only the data will tell whether it's a good idea or not.

Comment: @SamHartman: Put it in its own index. Since you're not qualifying on it, it won't benefit hugely from an index.

Comment: The string comparison isn't much of a hurdle. The correct use of indexes is the biggest thing - but your other points are all valid.

Comment: royalty_amount is a number, account_name is an index, I think you are right that there is no need for Distinct although changing that doesn't impact the time to get the results back. We have indexes on the individual fields but are you suggesting multiple fields in the index?  I have read about that but not tried.

Comment: @Strawberry: I meant a bit of a hurdle in the sense that it's a poor way to go about doing it, and changing to a better data structure could have a lot of ramifications.

Comment: @SeanPeace: Yes, composite indexes can help performance greatly in the right situation.

Comment: @Jacobm001  I don't know if mysql will do this, but Oracle will use an index to avoid a sort.  If your sort is big enough that it's causing a temporary table to be created, even when you are not qualifying on something in an index, a way to get to an ordered set of rows can depending on circumstances improve performance.